# Looking for nc to Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

Can you tell me if is there any site that I can find nc for Solaris 10 ?
Or if I can use another tool to send Syslog messages from Solaris to another server...

Comment: By the way, your question is off-topic here. It should have been asked / be moved to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You might just compile `nc` from source or download a package from a freeware repository, e.g. https://www.opencsw.org/package/netcat/ or http://solaris10pkgsrc.unixdev.net/ but why do you want to use nc in that case?

Solaris 10 syslog should already be able to send syslog messages to a remote server, have a look to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97988/how-do-i-send-all-information-in-var-adm-message-file-to-a-remote-system

Comment: Can you tell me what config need I issue to send a Syslog message from Solaris to another host ?